# Importing rows with their formulas from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import some columns from another sheet including formulas.
My code processes in 4 steps: 
* Clear all lines
* Filter lines 
* Copy these lines
* then paste them in the other sheet

Can someone tell me how can I modify the code below to paste these columns with their formulas:

```
Public Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lRow As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ws2.Range("B6:AP" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Scénarios de menace").Select
    Range("B4:Z398").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Analyse de risque").Select
    Range("B6:Z400").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="X"
    ws1.Range("B3:AP" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
    ws2.Activate: ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the `.Formula` Property:

```
ws2.Range("B6:Z400").Formula = ws1.range("B4:Z398").Formula
```

Above code is also cleaner by not using `.Select` or `.Copy .Paste` plus you defined your `Worksheets` then don't use it to `.Copy .Paste`.

Comment: I used this syntax but the problem is that my formulas calculate the result using other columns ( for example : =ConvertLikelihoodToString(J4;K4)). So when I import the formula it imports even the parameters ( J4 & K4) but in the active sheet the location of parameters is different.

Comment: is the parameters completely different?

Comment: No the same..but their locations are different

Comment: Then i don't understand the logic of copying the `.Formula` if the `.Formula` is not how you want it. Its then more logical to put a new `.Formula` in the Worksheet just how you need it.